# i have ERROR is that when a service called nusoap

Tags: node.js, web-services, express, wsdl, nusoap

```
exports.list = function(req, res){
var url = 'http://www.tribunal.besaba.com/php/servidorSoap.php?wsdl';
  soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
    var args = {name: '78763396'};
      client.getInhabilidad2(args, function(err, result) {
          res.send(result);
      });
  });
};
```

i have problem is that when  a service called nusoap get an error 
cannot call method getInhabilidad2 of undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is telling you that `client` is undefined. You should check what the `err` passed in the callback function of `soap.createClient` returns. There you'll find the root of your problem that is not creating your `client` to be able to call its `getInhabilidad2` later on.

Try:

```
function(err, client) {
    if(err) { 
        console.log("Error creating client: ", err); 
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: hello, thanks for the help: Error
{
  "code": "ECONNRESET"
}
when asking the error I get this error

Comment: "ECONNRESET" means the other end of the connection abruptly closed it. Check how the soap service provider is setup. Perhaps it doesn't like the way the URL you are sending it is formatted.